# Nonunital C*-Algebras: Closed Image

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Given C*-algebras $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$.

Consider a morphism: $\pi:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$.

Then its image is closed: $\mathrm{im}\pi\subsetneq\overline{\mathrm{im}\pi}$

The proof I know critically uses $\pi[1]=1$.

But what if either $1\notin\mathcal{A}$ or $1\notin\mathcal{B}$ or $\pi[1]\neq1$?

Comment: If it is a $*$-homomorphism, it is redundant to say it is a contraction, and the image must be closed, even if it weren't injective. If it is injective, then it is even isometric.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: I meant so saying that it is especially a contraction. Ok, but the proof I know uses that $\pi[1]=1\in\mathcal{B}$. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @JohnD: I hope you don't mind rolling back your edit. It looks better your way but it's horrible when using the search function. But still any edits are welcome! :)

Comment: @Freeze_S No problem.

Comment: Titles of the form "subject area : word" are less descriptive than they could be. Especially since the subject area is expressed by tags; there is a [tag for $C^*$ algebras](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c-star-algebras)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be the C*-algebra generated by $\pi(A)$.  Then $\pi(1)$ is a multiplicative identity for $C$, because it is one for $\pi(A)$ and multiplication is continuous.  Now you can apply the proof you know to $\pi:A\to C$.

Comment: That is great, thanks! :D